# How do I search for text within a tab delimited file and print this information?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, search

I need to search for something in a tab delimited text file. The user is supposed to input both the file and the thing that needs searching for. The programme is then supposed to return the whole line that the user inputted word is in. I have got two models so far because I've been coming at this problem from different angles. The first programme goes as follows:

```
import csv

searchfile = raw_input ('Which file do you want to search?   ')
try:
    input_file = open (searchfile, 'rU')
except:
    print "Invalid file. Please enter a correct file"

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open(searchfile, 'rb')) 
header = csv_file_object.next()   

data=[]                          
for row in csv_file_object:      
    data.append(row)             

searchA = raw_input ('which author?')

author_search = data[0::,0] == searchA

if author_search in searchfile:
    print author_search
```

The problem with the first programme is that this error pops up:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

I therefore attempted this method:

```
import csv

searchfile = raw_input ('Which file do you want to search?   ')
try:
    input_file = open (searchfile, 'rU')
except:
    print "Invalid file. Please enter a correct file"


with open(searchfile) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    d = list(reader)

searchtype = raw_input ('Search on author or journal/conference or [Q = quit]')


if searchtype == 'author':
    searchdataA = raw_input ("Input author name")
    if searchdataA in input_file:
        print line

elif searchtype == 'journal' or 'conference' or 'journal/conference':
    searchdataJ = raw_input ("input journal/conference name")
    if searchdataJ in d:
        print line

elif searchtype == 'Q':
    print "Program left"

else:
    print "please choose either author or journal/conference"
```

This is unable to get beyond inputting the search parameters.

Any help on where to go with either programme would be much appreciated, or if I'm completely on the wrong track then links to useful material would be great.

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of a file you'd be searching from?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making this a bit more complicated than it needs to be. Since you want to print the whole line that the target word appeared on, you don't really need the CSV module. You're not doing any of the sophisticated parsing it is capable of.

```
searchfile = raw_input ('Which file do you want to search?   ')
searchA = raw_input ('which author?')

with open(searchfile) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if searchA in line:
            print('  '.join(line.split()))
            break # remove this if you want to print all matches instead of
                  # just the first one
```

Notice that in the when printing the line, I first split the line (which splits on whitespace by default), then rejoin the fields with two spaces between them. I think doing something like this would be a good way to go for you since you're printing tab-separated fields on the console. Reducing that extra space will make your prints a bit easier to read, but using two spaces still makes it easy to distinguish the columns from each other.

You can generalize it by prompting your user for *any* search term, instead of specifying "author". This may be the way to go, since your second code snippet suggests that you may want to search for other fields, like "journal" or "conference":

```
target_term = raw_input("Which term or phrase would you like to find?")
```

Since this method searches in and prints the entire line, there's no need to deal with the separate columns and different kinds of search terms. It just looks at the whole row at once and prints a matching line.

Comment: looks like you typed faster than me an we posted the same answer. except for the `break` since i would be expecting maybe more than one matching line

Answer (score 1):

why not simply

```
fname = raw_input("Enter Filename")
author = raw_input("Enter Author Name:")
if author in open(fname,"rb").read():
   print "match found"
```

if you want to see the lines you could do

```
print re.findall(".*%s.*"%(author),open(fname,"rb").read())
```

as people point out it is better form to do

```
with open(fname,"rb") as f:
     data = print re.findall(".*%s.*"%(author),f.read())
```

although in CPython it will be garbage collected immediatly so its not really a problem....

Comment: I like the simplicity of your answers, but you're leaving a file descriptor unclosed in both cases.

Comment: not in CPython (which is 99.9% chance what OP is running) ... but your right I suppose it is a bad habit .... Ive never heard of any problems leaving read handles open even if they didnt GC (which in CPython they will right away)

Comment: I agree that it *usually* isn't a problem, but SO is an educational resource that is visited by a large number of newer programmers, so I think we should strongly emphasize good coding practices like cleaning up the resources you use, even if there are technical reasons we could get away with not doing it. Additionally, an exception raised during the read could definitely cause the interpreter to exit without cleaning up its file descriptors.

Comment: @skrrgwasme .... which would leave an open file descriptor ... that would not corrupt the file integrity... and would leave like a byte of unrecoverable memory(until next restart) ... anyway I added that they should probably use good coding practices

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not really using a different search method, depending on if you are searching for author, journal, conference or journal/conference. So you could actually do a full text search on the line. Therefore it is wise to collect all data you need from user BEFORE processing file, so you can output just the matching lines. If user passes a rather large CSV file, then your way would take up far too much memory.

```
with open(searchfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.find(searchA) > -1:
            print line
```

This way you are looping through the file as fast as possible and prints out all matching lines.

The `.find()` function returns the index to where in the string he found the match and otherwise `-1` if the string was not found. So from the value you could "estimate" on where the match was made, but if you really want to differentiate between author, journal, etc. then you will have to split the line. In my sample i will assume the author field to be the sixth field in the CSV line:

```
with open(searchfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split("\t")
        if len(fields) > 5:                    # check length of fields array
            if fields[5].find(searchA) > -1:   # search straight in author field
                print line                     # return full line
```

Comment: `line.find` returns the index in the case its found 0..N and -1 if its not `if -1` will evaluate to True

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is simply:

```
def check_file(file_name, author_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        if author_name in line:
            print "Found: ", line
```

Hope it can be useful.